python-dev-tools install error with pipenv
I am trying to install python-dev-tools using pipenv. I downloaded and installed python 3.12.8 from python.org and installed pipenv with pip. When I do pipenv install python-dev-tools --verbose in a new directory, it ends (stalls) with the message Building wheel for libcst (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'.

As someone, whose post has been deleted for some reason, just posted, it was indeed a problem with the Python version being too new and libcst apparently not yet compatible. It works when I go back to 3.10.
